# Puppet: How does hierarchy work if a role is matched?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I'm trying to understand how does Puppet hierarchy works.

My Puppet server's `hiera.yaml` looks like so:

```
[root@puppet puppet]# cat hiera.yaml 
:backends: 
  - yaml 
:yaml: 
  :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hieradata/%{::environment}' 
:hierarchy: 
  - fqdns/%{::fqdn} 
  - roles/%{::role} 
  - domains/%{::domain} 
  - common
```

There are modules which I want all servers to have so I've put them in the `common.yaml` file and there are role-specific modules which are included in each `role.yaml` file.

When a server which matches a role in Puppet starts, the modules from the `role.yaml` file are loaded first.
My question is:
Once a server is matched with a role... will it stop there? or will it continue in the hierarchy and load the modules under the `common.yaml` as well?

If not, How can I make sure that this is how it will behave?

Edit #1:
Here's an example of one of the `role.yaml` files:

```
[root@puppet roles]# cat dataorigin.yaml 
classes:
  - workspace

jdk_enable: true
jdk_ver: 1.6.0_41
component_ver: 1-1-5-17
tomcat_enable: true
debug_mode: true

fstab_params:
  mount1:
    mnt_src:  "isilonnj01.eyedcny.local:/ifs/Peer39/do_share"
    mnt_dest: "/doshare"
    mnt_opts: "tcp,hard,intr,noatime"
    mnt_dest_parent: ""
```

And the server's `site.pp` looks like so:

```
hiera_include("classes", [])
Package {  allow_virtual => false, }
node default {
include stdlib
}
```

Edit #2:
Here's an example of a motd module:

```
include stdlib
class motd {
    file { "/etc/custom_motd.sh":
    path    => '/etc/custom_motd.sh',
    ensure  => present,
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "775",
    content => template('motd/custom_motd.sh.erb'),
    #require => Class['nagios_client'],
    }

    file_line { 'enable motd':
    ensure  => present,
    line    => '/etc/custom_motd.sh',
    path    => '/etc/profile',
    require  => File['/etc/custom_motd.sh']
    }
}
```

The `motd module` is configured in the `common.yaml` file, and in the `role.yaml` file there's a module called workspace.
How can I tell Puppet to load the `motd module` from the `common.yaml` file?

Comment: How are these modules being included?  I assume you have a hiera_include, or are you doing something else?

Comment: Please check Edit #1

Comment: @ItaiGanot `How can I tell Puppet to lost the motd module from the common.yaml file?` Can you rephrase that please? You want Hiera to yield only the first match, not all? You want to selectively ignore one module? I'm not sure.

Comment: I had a typo there, lost = load , sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiera is a tool to lookup *data*. You give it a key name and it walks through its data files and returns the first match (which should be the most specific one) it comes up with, traversing downwards in its hierarchy.

[Using it within puppet](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#hiera-lookup-functions), you have more options what to do if there is more than one value for a key:

> ```
> hiera
>     Standard priority lookup. Gets the most specific value for a given key. 
>     This can retrieve values of any data type (strings, arrays, hashes) 
>     from Hiera.
> hiera_array
>     Uses an array merge lookup. Gets all of the string or array values 
>     in the hierarchy for a given key, then flattens them into a single 
>     array of unique values.
> hiera_hash
>     Uses a hash merge lookup. Expects every value in the hierarchy for
>     a given key to be a hash, and merges the top-level keys in each 
>     hash into a single hash. Note that this does not do a deep-merge 
>     in the case of nested structures.
> ```

Using `hiera` as an ENC to load modules works like [this](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#assigning-classes-to-nodes-with-hiera-hierainclude) (Emphasis added):

> Note that the **hiera_include** function uses an array merge lookup to retrieve the classes array; this means every node will get **every** class from its hierarchy.

So if you followed the docs and used `hiera_include`, all classes you specified throughout the hierarchy for a node will be loaded.

In your example, assuming `role=dataorigin`, and that `common.yaml` looks like this:

```
---
classes:
 - a
```

Your site.pp will cause the modules `workspace`, `stdlib` and `a` to be assigned to the querying node.

Comment: I'm having trouble to see how this answers my question...
My question was... Once a role is matched, will it continue loading the modules I specified in the `common.yaml` as well or will it stop there since there was a match in the roles?

Comment: You'll have to show us how exactly you use Hiera to load modules. As I mentioned, hiera just looks up data. everything else is up to your manifests.

Comment: Please tell me which info you need and I'll post it

Comment: @ItaiGanot: I've updated my answer, I hope it's clear enough now :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it now, please check my Edit #2, thanks.